# Post Model back to Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My aim is to export the clicked table, to excel (csv). This requires taking the Model on the page, and posting it to the server. But its providing difficult as its a list.

**How do I post the Model in the View, to the controller.**

Below is my code

View:

```
@model List<NameSpace.Property>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Export","Excel", FormMethod.Post))
{

   <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
}    

<table .... />
```

Controller:

```
     public void Export(List<Property> list)
    {

    }
```

Comment: i didn't understood your point

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Is it easier to understand now?

Comment: yes interesting question, do tell me when someone answers right...:D

Comment: @Doomsknight - I can do this for you but I would need to know what your property class and table data looks like

Comment: @heymega I would rather an example, so I can learn from it, and apply it myself. Rather than just copy and paste a solution. So assume that each "Property" is just, `Name | Street | PostCode` . Thanks

Comment: @Doomsknight - Why do you want to post the model (representing the table) to the server?  Can the information in the table be changed by the user?  Or is the table data static?

Comment: @Doomsknight - If the table is static data then you probably don't need to post anything back to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not state whether your table displays static data or dynamic data I have provided both solutions:

**STATIC:**

For example, if you request a url (lets say): `/home/index/1`.  The table data is retrieved for that id (of 1) and then displayed in a table in the view.

If the information in the table does not change then you do not need to post any information back to the server.  You should perform a `GET` request rather than a `POST` request to retrieve the CSV.

You would need to change the **view** to accept a model containing the original id that was requested and to use an action link rather than a form:

```
@model MyTableViewModel

@Html.ActionLink("Click here to export", "Export", "Excel", new { id = Model.Id });

<table .... />
```

Where the **view model** might be:

```
public class MyTableViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then your export **controller** action would be:

```
public FileContentResult Export(int id)
{
    string csv = //Retrieve the information for the provided id and convert to csv format
    return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "expostfilename.csv");
}
```

**DYNAMIC:**

The **view model** would no longer need the id so would become:

```
public class MyTableViewModel
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

The **view** could be written:

```
@model MyTableViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Home"))
{
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Customers.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers[i].Name)</td>
                    <td>Street: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers[i].Street)</td>
                    <td>PostCode: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers[i].PostCode)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

And the **controller** export action:

```
public FileContentResult Export(MyTableViewModel vm)
{
   string csv = //convert view model (vm) to csv
   return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "expostfilename.csv");
}
```

Comment: I did origionally think of the static idea, as put in my first edit of the question. However, it doesn't take into account ordering etc. Which in theory could be added to the view model. I went with clientside SWF exporting, which works great. The fields would be `HiddenFor`

Answer (score 1):

Controller Action

```
    public void Export(List<Property> list)
    {

    }
```

Property Class

```
public class Property
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

Html Table

```
<table id="my-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Chris</td>
            <td>Awesome Street</td>
            <td>DH9 4LD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sean</td>
            <td>Lame Street</td>
            <td>DH8 4SR</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    var aData = {};

    $('#my-table tbody tr').each(function(index, value) {

        aData['list[' + index + '].Name'] = $(value).children().eq(0).text();
        aData['list[' + index + '].Street'] = $(value).children().eq(1).text();
        aData['list[' + index + '].Postcode'] = $(value).children().eq(2).text();

    });

    $.post("@Url.Action("Export")", aData, function(data) {


    });


</script>
```

This should be enough to get you started. Hope this helps

**Update**

Alternatively if you did not want a Jquery specific solution, you could output your data in hidden fields

```
    <input type="hidden" name="[0].Name" value="Chris" />
    <input type="hidden" name="[0].Street" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="[0].Postcode" value="...." />

    <input type="hidden" name="[1].Name" value="Sean" />
    <input type="hidden" name="[1].Street" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="[1].Postcode" value="...." />
```

and this would get submitted in your form